# solving linear system 6x6 matrix using sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

i am trying to solve a matrix that has 6x6 matrices as it's entries(elements)

i tried multiplying the inverse of gen to the solution matrix, but i don't trust the correctness of the answer am getting.

```
from sympy import Eq, solve_linear_system, Matrix,count_ops,Mul,horner
import sympy as sp

a, b, c, d, e,f = sp.symbols('a b c d e f')

ad = Matrix(([43.4,26.5,115,-40.5,52.4,0.921],
  [3.78,62.9,127,-67.6,110,4.80],
  [41.25,75.0,213,-88.9, 131, 5.88],
  [-10.6,-68.4,-120,64.6,-132,-8.49],
  [6.5,74.3,121,-72.8,179,29.7],
  [1.2,30.7,49.7,-28.7,91,29.9]))
fb= Matrix(([1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1]))

ab = Matrix(([-0.0057],
        [0.0006],
        [-0.0037],
        [0.0009],
        [0.0025],
        [0.0042]))
az = sp.symbols('az')
bz = sp.symbols('bz')
fz = sp.symbols('fz')

gen = Matrix(([az, fz, 0, 0, 0, 0,bz],
            [fz,az,fz,0,0,0,bz],
            [0,fz,az,fz,0,0,bz],
                [0,0,fz,az,fz,0,bz],
                [0,0,0,fz,az,fz,bz],
                [0,0,0,0,fz,az,bz]))

answer = solve_linear_system(gen,a,b,c,d,e,f)
first_solution = answer[a]
df = count_ops(first_solution)
print(df,first_solution)
disolved = zip(first_solution.simplify().as_numer_denom(),(1,-1))
dft = Mul(*[horner(b)**e for b,e in disolved])
dff = count_ops(dft)
print(dff,dft)
_1st_solution = dft.subs({az:ad,fz:fb,bz:ab},simultaneous = True).doit()
print(_1st_solution)
```

when i ran my code it raised sympy.matrices.common.ShapeError

Comment: Your question seems to be pretty good, except for one thing. Python gives traceback messages with much detail that is very helpful. What is the full traceback message for that code?

Comment: the trace back error is too long. pls, copy and run the code to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful when using `horner` with expressions containing commutative symbols that are actually noncommutative (in your case because they represent matrices). Your `dft` expression is

```
(az**2*bz - bz*fz**2)/(az*(az*(az + fz) - 2*fz**2) - fz**3)
```

but should maybe be

```
(az**2 - fz**2)*(az*(az*(az + fz) - 2*fz**2) - fz**3)**(-1)*bz
```

You would have received a correct expression if you had created the symbols as noncommutative (as shown below).

But you can't use `horner` with non-commutative symbols, so I just rearranged the expression by hand; you will have to check to see that the ordering is right. As an alternative to doing the factoring by hand you might also try using `factor_nc` to help you -- but it won't handle `horner` like expression factoring:

```
>>> ax, bz, fz = symbols('az bz fz, commutative=False)
>>> (az**2*bz - fz**2*bz)
az**2*bz - fz**2*bz
>>> factor_nc(_)
(az**2 - fz**2)*bz
```

Comment: It already knows that you can't do this multiplication (and thus the error). If you just make your symbols `commutative=False` and factor the `dft` without horner -- by hand, perhaps -- you should be able to get an expression that will efficiently accept the actual matrix values you want to use in place of the symbols.

Comment: thanks, smichr :))   you've delivered me again. thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer. If it looks good to you, please feel free to mark it as an answer.